# I want to show selected value of dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Selected value is not coming when I am trying to check, drop down list is showing all the names, but when I am trying to show the selected value of the dropdownlist in the controller, option is not coming.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    Class1 cs1 = new Class1();

    return View(cs1);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index1(Class1 cs)
{
    var selecteditem = cs.psudetail.Find(p => p.Section_PSU == cs.psudetail.ToString());
    if (selecteditem != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Model class:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public List<PSUMaster> psudetail
        {
            get
            {
                PSUEntities pe = new PSUEntities();
                return pe.PSUMasters.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the View with Model:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Class1
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Index1";
}
<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.psudetail, new SelectList(Model.psudetail, "S_no", "Section_PSU"), "--Select PSU--")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a property that can "store" the selection you make in the list. Extend the view model (`Class1`) to include a property `SelectedPSU`. I guess that `S_no` in the `PSUMaster` is the ID, and of type integer. Otherwise adjust the code accordingly!

I have also changed the list to be just a list, and then the controller can worry about populating it. This pattern fits MVC better (keep the model simple).

Updated class:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class PsuViewModel
    {
        public int SelectedPSU { get; set; }

        public List<PSUMaster> PSU { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next, the controller has to be updated to pass the list to the view model in the `GET` `Index` method:

```
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    var pe = new PSUEntities();

    return View(new PsuViewModel {
        PSU = pe.PSUMasters.ToList()
    });
}
```

Now we can use the `SelectedPSU` property in our view:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Class1
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Index1";
}
<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPSU, new SelectList(Model.PSU, "S_no", "Section_PSU"), "--Select PSU--")
```

...and we can get the ID in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index1(PsuViewModel model)
{
    var pe = new PSUEntities();
    var selectedPsu = pe.PSUMasters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.S_no == model.SelectedPSU);

    if (selectedPsu != null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```